# How to get a circle to move when you click on it in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, onclick, p5.js, mouseclick-event

I'm making a whack-a-mole game based on a 3x3 grid for one of my classes but i'm having trouble getting the mole(an ellipse made using p5.js) to move to a different grid square on click. I want it to automatically move after 7 seconds which i achieved using function sleep(milliseconds), but if the player clicks the mole before the 7 seconds is up then I want it to switch grid squares right then. This is my code for mousePressed and moveCircle.

```
    function mousePressed() {
      var distance = int(dist(mouseX, mouseY, moleX, moleY));
      if(distance <= circleDiameter/2 ) {
         moveCircle();
         score += 1;
       } 
      document.getElementById('playerScore').innerHTML=score;
    }

    function moveCircle(){
      var randomX = [110, 260, 410];
      var randomY = [95, 245, 395];
      var moleX = random(randomX);
      var moleY = random(randomY);

   }
```

Comment: What `sleep()` function are you using? Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: Hi I'm not quite sure how to do that because the code uses p5js to run but i put it on the p5js online editor with the code attached https://alpha.editor.p5js.org/brikin/sketches/HkRAc7gsf

Comment: In the future, please post a [mcve] directly in your post. We don't need you to include all of P5.js or anything, but we need to see all of the code required to run your program to see the problem ourselves. What you have in the editor is a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sleep()` function is **not** how you should handle timing in P5.js, or in JavaScript in general.

Your `sleep()` function causes your program to become completely unresponsive, which is bad for a lot of reasons. One problem is that your event code will not trigger, which is the problem you're seeing.

Instead, you need to use the `millis()` function or the `frameCount` variable to handle your timing without blocking your whole program. Here's a small example:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(200,200);
    background(32);
}

function draw(){
    // 60 frames is 1 second
    if(frameCount % 60 == 0){
      ellipse(random(width), random(height), 25, 25);   
    }
}
```

This code uses the `frameCount` variable along with the `%` modulus operator to check whether 1 second has elapsed. In other words, this program draws a circle every second.

You need to do something similar to move your mole, which will allow your event code to be fired even while the mole is "waiting".

Answer (score -1):

`int(dist(mouseX, mouseY, moleX, moleY))`

This `int` keyword does not make sense. If you want it to be a whole number, use the `Math.round()` function (or just `round()` in p5js).

Try `console.log`ing the distance variable.