# How to reset game score and button text

Tags: javascript, html, function, p5.js

I'm making a whack a mole game for a school project and I've gotten the actual game to work, however I'm having an issue resetting the game once the 30 second timer runs out. The game is made with javascript and p5.js and as of right now when you load the page, the game div display is set to hidden, but when you click "begin" the display changes to block and the timer starts (the game is on github for reference https://abm96testgithub.github.io/whackamole/). When the 30 seconds are up, the "begin" button changes to "reset" and the game display goes back to "none" (both done using document.getElementByID).

Is there a way to make it so that when the player hits "reset" the entire page will reload or so that the button will read "begin" again and the score will reset?

I know I can make a separate reset button with a function for this, but I feel like it would mess up the aesthetic of the page to have two buttons.
The html for the button when the page first loads is

```
<button id="startButton" onclick="startGame();startTimer()">Begin!</button>
```

and the javascript for it is

```
function startGame() {    
    document.getElementById('sketch-holder').style.display = "block";
}

function countdown () {
    var startCountdown = setInterval(function() {
        document.getElementById('timerVar').innerHTML = counter + "s";
        counter--;

        if (counter < 0) {
            clearInterval(startCountdown);
            document.getElementById('sketch-holder').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('startButton').innerHTML = "Reset";
        }
    }, 1000)
}

function startTimer() {   

    if (timerOn === false) {
        timerOn = true;
        countdown();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little strange to use `setInterval()` when you're using P5.js. P5.js has its own internal timing mechanisms, which we talked about in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49619295/how-to-get-a-circle-to-move-when-you-click-on-it-in-javascript).

Instead of using `setInterval()`, I'd use the `millis()` function or the `frameCount` variable to perform timing logic. See my code in my answer to your last question:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(200,200);
    background(32);
}

function draw(){
    // 60 frames is 1 second
    if(frameCount % 60 == 0){
      ellipse(random(width), random(height), 25, 25);   
    }
}
```

This code draws a circle once per second. This is just an example, but you could do something very similar to reset your game after 30 seconds.

Then to reset your game, all you really need to do is set any variables you're using back to their default values. Try writing a `reset()` function that does exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, Instead of `Button` You can go witha `a` tag with `void` href then on click you can add `href="javascript:window.location.href=window.location.href"` which will reload the page.

```js
function startGame() {

    document.getElementById('sketch-holder').style.display = "block";
}



        function countdown () {
          var startCountdown = setInterval(function(){
            document.getElementById('timerVar').innerHTML = counter + "s";
            counter--;

            if (counter < 0) {
              clearInterval(startCountdown);
              document.getElementById('sketch-holder').style.display = "none";
              document.getElementById('startButton').innerHTML = "Reset";
              document.getElementById('startButton').setAttribute("href", 'javascript:window.location.href=window.location.href"');
        }
    }, 1000)
}
       function startTimer() {

         if (timerOn === false) {
         timerOn = true;
         countdown();
    }
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)"id="startButton" onclick="startGame();startTimer()">Begin!</a>
```